# Error when scraping JSON webpage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a JSON webpage and it is not working. Not sure what is wrong. Here is my js/jQuery code:

```
 $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
    console.log(data.contents);
    var ethPrice = JSON.parse(data.contents).price_usd;
    alert(ethPrice)
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (scripts.js:6)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLScriptElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Please Help. 
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Quick note: `alert` won't show you the object details. Use `console.log`

Comment: What does the output of your `console.log(data.contents);` look like? I bet the first character is `o`.

Comment: remove the `&callback=?` from your GET request

Comment: Your data.contents is an array and so you don't need to parse. Simply use:  data.contents[0].price_usd

Answer (score 0):

Look like your json result is an array json. So, it cannot have access to field since it is array. Probably, you need this.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
    console.log(data.contents);
    var response = JSON.parse(data.contents);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i ++) {
        var ethPrice = response[i].price_usd;
        alert(ethPrice);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You might also need to confirm if data has contents.

$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
encodeURIComponent('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/') 
+ '&callback=?', function (data) {
if (data && data.contents) {
    console.log(data.contents);
 var contents = JSON.parse(data.contents);
//loop through contents for a price_usd attribute
for (let i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
if (contents[i].price_usd) {
alert(contents[i].price_usd)
}
}
```

}
    });